# how to manipulate space-between in a space-between without moving the other objects in the parent element

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

The title may be somewhat confusing but what i'm trying to reach is that my footer has 3 elements namely `<address>` (contact info), `<img>`(logo) and a `div`(containing 3 images with social media buttons). What I'm trying to reach is that the they're stretched over the container with space-between via `display: flex`.  This works pretty fine but I want the last `div` to have more space between the different social media buttons. So I gave it a bigger width and did another space-between so the images are evenly a bit further from each other.

The problem is that when I do this, the other object in the first space between move somewhat to the left which causes the logo to be uncentered. Is there a way to manipulate this?

```css
footer{
  margin-top: 10rem;
}


.footer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.social-media{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 17rem;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container footer">
    <address class="contact-info">
      <h2 class="contact-info-title">Bxl tours</h2>
      <a href="mailto:bxltours@info.be?subject=question" class="link info-txt ">bxltours@info.be</a><br>
      Doornikslaan 5 <br>
      1000 Brussel
    </address>
    <img src="./assets/img/logo_1@288x.png" alt="BXL Tours" width="54" height="77">

    <div class="social-media">
      <img src="./assets/img/devine@288x.png" alt="devine" width="44" height="44">
      <img src="./assets/img/facebook@288x.png" alt="facebook" width="44" height="44">
      <img src="./assets/img/twitter@288x.png" alt="twitter" width="44" height="44">
    </section>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

`justify-content: space-between` is not going to help you as it applies spacing evenly between flex children (and you cannot denote that you want the logo to be centered in the footer irregardless of the other elements).

Instead, one way would be to use flex to center the logo and `position: absolute;` the address and social media icons. Note that now the elements *may* overlap in certain breakpoints, so you'll have to take that into account.

```css
footer{
  margin-top: 10rem;
}


.footer{
  display: flex;
}

img {
  margin: auto;
}

.contact-info,
.social-media {
  position: absolute;
}

.social-media{
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 17rem;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container footer">
    <address class="contact-info">
      <h2 class="contact-info-title">Bxl tours</h2>
      <a href="mailto:bxltours@info.be?subject=question" class="link info-txt ">bxltours@info.be</a><br>
      Doornikslaan 5 <br>
      1000 Brussel
    </address>
    <img src="./assets/img/logo_1@288x.png" alt="BXL Tours" width="54" height="77">

    <div class="social-media">
      <img src="./assets/img/devine@288x.png" alt="devine" width="44" height="44">
      <img src="./assets/img/facebook@288x.png" alt="facebook" width="44" height="44">
      <img src="./assets/img/twitter@288x.png" alt="twitter" width="44" height="44">
    </section>
  </div>
</footer>
```